# Return all sets of combinations from a matrix, such that no member of each set is highly correlated with another

Tags: r, matrix, combinations, combinatorics, correlation

If I have a symmetric matrix (of for example correlations between variables), I am looking for a way to return all combinations of those variables that are above or below some threshold correlation with each other. I can't quite grasp at the moment how I could do this with `expand.grid` or `combn` (if you can). Please note, I **DON'T** want just pairs of variables.

Imagine I want to return every possible combination of a group of numbers, (unordered, so not caring about position of numbers within each set). If there are two numbers I'd just have {1}, {2}, {1,2}. If there are 3 numbers it would be {1} , {2} , {3} , {1,2} , {1,3} , {2,3} , {1,2,3}.

I want to do the same thing here with variables, BUT I want to restrict the combinations returned so that no members of the set have a correlation above a certain threshold (in the example below the threshold is **> 0.7** ) with any other member of the set.

```
set.seed(8) # to reproduce the numbers I have
n <- 5
m <- diag(n)
m[lower.tri(m, diag=F)] <- round( runif( sum( 1:(n-1) ) ) , 2 )
m[upper.tri(m, diag=F)] <- m[lower.tri(m, diag=F)]
m

#In this case I want to return the combinations:
1,2
1,3
1,4
1,5
2,4
4,5
1,2,4 # meaning that none of the pairs {1,2} {1,4} {2,4} share a correlation greater than 0.6
1,4,5 # ditto for {1,4} {1,5} {4,5}

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] 1.00 0.47 0.21 0.65 0.29
[2,] 0.47 1.00 0.80 0.32 0.93
[3,] 0.21 0.32 1.00 0.72 0.77
[4,] 0.80 0.72 0.93 1.00 0.64
[5,] 0.65 0.29 0.77 0.64 1.00
```

Can anyone help suggest a way?

Comment: I don't understand the "1,2,3" in the end ?

Comment: Because I don't want just the pairs of variables. Imagine I want to return every possible combination of a group of numbers, (unordered, so not caring about position of numbers within each set). If there are two numbers I'd just have {1}, {2}, {1,2}. If there are 3 numbers it would be {1} , {2} , {3} , {1,2} , {1,3} , {2,3} , {1,2,3}. I want to do the same thing here with variables, BUT I want to restrict the combinations returned so that no members of the set have a correlation of > 0.6 with any other member of the set. Does this make more sense now? I can update the question text.

Comment: @Juba, I think he's identifying the four independent elements whose crosscorrelations are given in this matrix.  He wants not only pairwise "correlation < 0.6)"  but "set-wise" as well.  Simon-- chime in if I'm wrong here.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Exactly! Thank you for précising my longwinded and imprecise explantion of what I was after!

Comment: Then how are the cross-correlations represented in a matrix? Meaning, which index corresponds to the cross correlation between independent vectors {1} and {3}, and which one corresponds to {1} vs {2} and {3}?

Comment: @Arun Indeed you have spotted a mistake in my example which makes my explanation of the question useless, because 2 & 3 are highly correlated with each other. I apologise for wasting peoples time with a bad explanation. I will update the question and example so it works properly!

Comment: @Arun updated the question. Can you let me know if it is more obvious what I am trying achieve for other reading this question please?

Comment: @SimonO101, yes, it is clear to me now. I've given an answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not the prettiest solution, but this works:

```
o <- unlist(lapply(2:nrow(m), function(x) {
    i1 <- combn(seq_len(nrow(m)), x)
    apply(i1, 2, function(y) {
        if (all(combn(y, 2, function(z) m[z[1], z[2]] < 0.7) == TRUE))
            y
        else 
            NA
    })
}), recursive=F)
o[!is.na(o)]

# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 3
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 1 4
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 1 5
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 2 4
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] 4 5
# 
# [[7]]
# [1] 1 2 4
# 
# [[8]]
# [1] 1 4 5
```

Comment: Beautiful! What's not pretty about this?! Can you please explain what this command achieves? `combn(y, 2, function(z) m[z[1], z[2]] < 0.7)`. I think I get it - does it check pairwise correlations between each element of the column from y which is a matrix of the possible combinations of variables from the matrix 'm' of given length? Thank you, thank you!